# Call public method in multiple child lightning web components

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components

I have created multiple instances of child component in parent component using iteration.

```
<template for:each={vohmObjectList} for:item="vohmobject" for:index="index">
  <div key={vohmobject.fields.Id}>
    <c-vehicle-or-heavy-machine
      vohm-object-id={vohmobject.fields.Id}
      vohm-h-m-v-form-field={vohmobject.fields.HMV_Form__c}
      type-picklist-values={typePicklistValues}
      index-value={index}
      ondeleted = {handleVOHMDelete}
    ></c-vehicle-or-heavy-machine>
  </div>
</template>
```

There is a public method in child component which returns all the data present there.

```
@api 
getVOHMObject() {
    const vohmObjectInput = {};
    vohmObjectInput[TYPE_FIELD.fieldApiName] = this.vohmTypeField;
    vohmObjectInput[DISPLAY_NAME_FIELD.fieldApiName] = this.vohmDisplayNameField;
    vohmObjectInput[STAND_FIELD.fieldApiName] = this.vohmStandField;
    vohmObjectInput[LENGTH_FIELD.fieldApiName] = this.vohmLengthField;
    vohmObjectInput[WIDTH_FIELD.fieldApiName] = this.vohmWidthField;
    vohmObjectInput[HEIGHT_FIELD.fieldApiName] = this.vohmHeightField;
    vohmObjectInput[WEIGHT_FIELD.fieldApiName] = this.vohmWeightField;
    vohmObjectInput[HMV_FORM_FIELD.fieldApiName] = this.vohmHMVFormField;
    vohmObjectInput[VOHM_ID_FIELD.fieldApiName] = this.vohmObjectId;

    return vohmObjectInput;
}
```

I want to call this method for all the child components and put returned data in a list (so that I can update these records by calling apex method).

I tried using querySelector thinking that it would return a list of all child component instances, but it only returns first instance.

```
const objectsToUpdate = this.template.querySelector('c-vehicle-or-heavy-machine');
```

Is there any way to call @api method for all child components?

Comment: `querySelectorAll` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried using querySelector thinking that it would return a list of all child component instances, but it only return first instance.

you can use `querySelectorAll` if you want to fetch all of the them and not just the first.

Comment: Thank you, it works!

Answer (score 1):

```
@track childComponentsDataList = [];
    connectedCallback() {
        this.childComponents = this.template.querySelectorAll('c-vehicle-or-heavy-machine');
        this.childComponentsDataList = this.childComponents.map(comp=>comp.getVOHMObject());
    }
```

Note: Do not use forEach function or for loop as it will have performance issues because you will have to keep adding to same array (by using push). Instead when you use map function, it create new array instance and return it - this is best practice as per defined by many other libraries like angular and react and even LWC.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable insight. this.template.querySelectorAll was returning HTML Collection, I had to covert it to Array before using map function on it.